# How to get current_user in Rails using devise_token_auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use **devise_token_auth** with **devise** for auth and registration. Everything goes well: I can sign in, sign out using api and web interface. But I can't get **current_user** devise variable (nil).

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path(current_user.id) %> |
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %> |
    <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path) %>
  <% end %>
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end
```

I need this variable as a global for using, for example, in application.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# app/controllers/test_controller.rb
class TestController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Notice the `before_action`.
`authenticate_user!` is responsible for setting `current_user`.

Comment: I have controller Payments but I need current_user as a global variable. E.g. I want to sue it in application.html.erb

Comment: Ok, when I wrote this method, json returns me current user. But when I try to write user = current_user in def index and then in html try <% user.email %> get nothing.

Comment: I think that you want to use an instance variable in order to pass the user to the view: `@user`.

Comment: Use `@user` in the view as well.

Comment: `<h5><% @user.email %></h5>` still not displaying